# Navbar flashing when i click it

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to write a website with html css and javascript, when applying mobile support the nav bar (burger) is just flashing the menu when i click it. i have obviously missed something but i cant find it any help? probably something obvious i cant see

Thanks :)

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NEXT WEBSITE</title>
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></LINK>
</head> 
<body>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar__container">
                    <a href="/" id="navbar__logo">LOGO</a:>
                    <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
                        <span class="bar"></span>
                        <span class="bar"></span>
                        <span class="bar"></span>
                    </div>  
                    <ul class="navbar__menu">
                         <li class="navbar__item">
                               <a href="/" class="navbar__links">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="navbar__item">
                               <a href="/gallery.html" class="navbar__links"> Gallery </a>    
                        </li>
                            <li class="navbar__item">
                                  <a href="/" class="navbar__links">Products</a>
                            </li>
                         <li class="navbar__btn">
                                 <a href="/" class="button">Sign Up</a>
                          </li>
                     </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif';
}

.navbar{
    background: #131313;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    z-index: 999;

}

.navbar__container{
    display: flex;  
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 101;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    /* first value does top and bottom second does left and right */
}




#navbar__logo{
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top,#ff0844 0%,#ffb199 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor : pointer;
    text-decoration:none ;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.fa-gem{
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar__menu{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar__item{
    height: 80px;
}



.navbar__links{
    color: #ffff ;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 4rem;
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar__btn{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.button{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #f7062f;
    color: #fff;
}

.button:hover{
    background: #4837ff;
    transition: all 0.3s,ease;
}
/* colours for hovering over stuff*/


.navbar__links:hover{
color: #f7062f;
transition: all 0.3s,ease;
}
 /* colours for hovering over stuff*/




 @media screen and (max-width :950px){
.navbar__container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0;

 }

.navbar__menu{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top :-1000px;
        opacity: 0;

        /* j top :-1000px;
        opacity: 0;
        background-color: #131313; */
        transition: all 0.5s,ease;
        height: 50vh;
        z-index: -1;
}


.navbar__menu.active{ 
    background-color: #131313;
    top:100%;
    /* show menu drop down*/
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s,ease;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 50vh;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
/* javascript to trigger menu drop down*/


#navbar__logo{
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.navbar__toggle .bar{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.3s,ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
}

.navbar__item{
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar__links{
    text-align:center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}


#mobile-menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 5%;
    transform: translate(5%,20%);
}

.navbar__btn{
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.button{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0;
}


.navbar__toggle .bar{
    display:block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    
#mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2){
    opacity: 0;
}
#mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1){
    transform: translateY(8px)rotate(45deg) ;
}   
#mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3){
    transform: translateY(-8px)rotate(-45deg) ;
} 
 }
```

js:

```
 const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu')
 //targeting menu bar thats inside mobile menu div
 const menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu') 
//

menu.addEventListener('click',function(){
menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
menuLinks.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

just trying to toggle the menu onto the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a href="/" id="navbar__logo">LOGO</a:>`
Because in this line of code you have inserted `:` in the closing tag.
Remove it then try again.

I am also not much experience but I tried deducing what's happening is that
When there was `:` then if we check the code in inspect element then the div came inside anchor tag, thus when you click the burger menu then the a tag also gets clicked which redirects to '/' route thus page refreshed and to you it looks like flashing

screen shot with `:` in `a` tag

[image]

without `:` in `a` tag

[image]

You all can correct me if I said something wrong.

Comment: nailed it bro :)